# Is it possible to set up a Linux box with distcc to build my XCode projects?

Tags: objective-c, linux, xcode, build, distributed

I have a mac mini on which I do some iphone and other experimental development. It is hideously slow to build some of the larger projects I have tried out (like 3d engines and such). There are some support for distributed builds with distcc and I have a quad core linux box just standing idle beside it.

The question is: is it possible to set up a distcc environment on the linux box that would build ordinary mac objective c or c++ projects, or even iphone projects? Has anyone tried/succeeded in doing this, or is it just not possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.  No, it's not easy.  But I've done most of the hard work for you, and I've even collected it all at [toolwhip.googlecode.com](http://toolwhip.googlecode.com/).  The various READMEs in the source there describe what's been done.  I can't provide support for it right now, but I'm using it with very positive results.

Answer (score 2):

The sources for  most of the Apple toolchain (excluding Xcode of course) are available [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/release/developer-tools-312/) including [distcc](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/distcc/distcc-1088/). All will run on Darwin, so one possibility is to run them via a VM in Darwin on your Linux box. It looks like many popular Linux distros already have distcc packages (e.g. [Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/dapper/distcc)), though I'm not sure how they differ from Apple's code.

Comment: Darwin may not include all libraries ie: Cocoa

Comment: Preprocessing and linking aren't usually distributed by distcc. The only requirement for the machine running distccd is that it have the same compiler version. It might even be possible to build Apple's GCC as a cross-compiler on Linux.