# Is it possible to use distcc in osx for openbsd box?

Tags: macos, gcc, bsd, openbsd

I found the only one simillar question but that's for linux and xcode only...

[Is it possible to set up a Linux box with distcc to build my XCode projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854675/is-it-possible-to-set-up-a-linux-box-with-distcc-to-build-my-xcode-projects)

im really interested to use OSX GCC for OPENBSD BOX. because my server is really slow, and all I need is file sharing and printing at home. I like to use ports very much, especially rebuilding all packages for slow cpu, it's really noticable difference, anyway, IMHO, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using distcc is not the issue here. What you need is a OS X -> OpenBSD crosscompiling toolchain, which is something that works well.

Some reading:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler
- http://www.landley.net/ols/ols2007/tutorial.txt
- http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler

Comment: that what dcc could do? --> A gcc wrapper that speeds compilation by transparently distributing work across several machines

Comment: distcc distributes workload among computers. A cross-compiler compiles for a target that is different from the one it runs on.